# R code that will group_by multiple columns and summarize when a data element appears across the column group

Tags: r

How can I summarize the counts of a set of specific factors that appear across a group of columns?

I'm working on summarizing a set of specific factors that appear across a group of columns in my data set (specifically, medical procedure codes that can appear across 15 different procedure columns). I'd like to group the columns and then summarize any time one of a set list of codes appears in any of those columns. This can mean that the specified codes aren't mutually exclusive to a single record of data, there will be overlap in a row of appearances by multiple procedure codes that I'm looking for.

I've used the following dummy df to run a quick test. I want to summarize the count of data points "b" and "e" across columns "Y" and "Z". Clearly, my summary won't work how I want it to, but that's as far as I've gotten.

```
library(dplyr)

Mydata <- data.frame(W = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                     X = c(20, 30, 45, 54, 65, 78, 97, 102, 123, 156),
                     Y = c("a","b","c","d","e","e","f","f","f","g"),
                     Z = c("c","a","b","b","c","d","e","e","g","h"))

 test_group <- Mydata %>%   summarize_at(c(z, w), n = n())
```

Expected results would be a table with the following:

```
Specified_Data  n
             b  3
             e  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another user posted an answer but looks like they pulled it down. However, it does work, so I figured I'd throw the code in. Works with dplyr.

```
Mydata %>%
  select(Y, Z) %>%
  gather(var, val) %>%
  filter(val %in% c("b", "e")) %>%
  count(val)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  val       n
  <chr> <int>
1 b         3
2 e         4
```

There is a warning message after the console result, but it doesn't seem to have any impact on the code line working. Message as follows:

```
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```